# How to debug "The type initializer for 'my class' threw an exception"

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am getting the exception: `The type initializer for 'my class' threw an exception.` in my browser after running my web application. Since this seems to be an error message generated from the view (.aspx), there is no way I can see the stack trace or any log for the source of this error.

I have read a bit around the net and one solution to debugging is to throw a `TypeInitializationException` and then looking at the inner exception to find out what was wrong. How can I do this when I don't know where to surround code with a try/catch ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the constructors of 'my class' ?

Comment: Do you have a static constructor? Or do you use any static variables in the class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be caused by a bad static constructor, or by bad inline initialization of static properties/fields. For instance:

```
class A
{
    static A()
    {
        //buggy code here
    }
    static SomeField f = new ThisClassThrowsWhenConstructed(); // <-- or here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Even today 8 years on I was trying to use a class Library to store Global strings making them static like so: 

' public static readonly string ApplicationUrlEncoded = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";'.

This gave me an initialiser error. Changing them to:

' public const string ApplicationUrlEncoded = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";'

Resolved my problem. Not sure why, but there you go!

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found reason for this issue is AppConfig settings of my project. Yes, I have two C# projects, **Project1** and **Project2**.

**Project1** is contains the Static class **MyDetails**

```
public static MyDetails
{
  public static int _LogLevel = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogLevel"])

  public static GetData()
   {
     ----code----
     ----code----
   }
}
```

I have following appConfig settings in Project1

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LogLevel" value="5"/>
</appSettings>
```

The function **MyDetails.GetData()** is being called From **Project2** which is the project I am debugging now. Since **Project2**  is the target project,  the line **ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogLevel"]** will try to read setting LogLevel from **Project2**. but **LogLevel** setting is only available in **Project1**. so, we need to add appsettings in **Project2**.

The issue The type initializer for threw an exception has been solved after adding  the folowing appsettings in appConfig of **Project2**,

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LogLevel" value="5"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown when the static constructor of 'my class' crashes. Please put your breakpoint there.

Comment: in fact, the constructor was never being hit because the problem was with a static global variable set to a non-existing parameter key in the web.config. I removed the line and now it works...

Comment: Yes this is possible because static (and not static as well) variable inline assignments are compiled by C# compiler into constructor. That explains your situation. Answer from @spender mentions this.

Comment: I suppose this is because a static variable inline assignment is executed differently than if it was not assigned inline...

Answer (score 0):

There is something that when wrong in your static constructor of the class, and instead of throwing that error, the `CLR` will throw `TypeInitializationException`.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: if you have multiple static constructors within the same class that errored out, either put breakpoint on the first static constructors or on all of them.

The unusual thing about static constructor is that when there's issue during construction, it doesn't error out at the point where the construction happens. It errors out later, at the point when the object that was statically constructed is being called/used.

For example, in my case: I have 3 static constructors: A, B, C. Program errors out and paused at a point when value of C is accessed. I put breakpoint on the static constructor for C and the breakpoint didn't get hit. What happens?

Turns out static constructor for B is bad and so the static construction of C doesn't happen. It's confusing because one would think that the error should have popped up as soon as the construction of B failed.